# Regular expression in python to capture first operator

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the following pattern:

> name1 operator name2

where 'operator' is one of &,^ or |

The groups should be `(name1 operator name2,name1,operator,name2)`

Now, either name can also include `&,| or ^` and white spaces, but only the first appearance will make the operator. Further appearances will be considered to be a part of name2.

I've been sturggling with this for quite some time now, and I have

```
\s*(\w+\s*\w*)\s*([&|^])\s*(\w+\s*\&*\w+)
```

Doesn't seem very cleaver, doesn't work either. Also, if there's a function similar to `str.partition()` that can work with regex and limit the results to 1, it would be great. I couldn't find one.

Any ideas for a regex or function? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [163]: re.split(r'\s*([&|^])\s*', 'name1|name2', maxsplit=1)
Out[163]: ['name1', '|', 'name2']
```

`maxsplit=1` causes `re.split` to make at most 1 match:

```
In [164]: re.split(r'\s*([&|^])\s*', 'name1|nam^e2', maxsplit=1)
Out[164]: ['name1', '|', 'nam^e2']
```

You could also use a non-greedy search:

```
In [184]: re.search(r'\s*(.*?)\s*([&|^])\s*(.*?)\s*', 'name1 | nam^e2').groups()
Out[184]: ('name1', '|', 'nam^e2')
```

This has the advantage of also tripping off the whitespace at the beginning and end of the string.

The non-greediness of the first group, `(.*?)` allows `([&|^])` to match the first occurrence of `&`, `|`, or `^`.

Comment: Nice how we wrote almost the same regex at the same time, but I used `.+?` so it won't match lone `|` or `foo&`

Answer (score 1):

An option to remove extra spaces:

```
>>> re.search(r'^\s*(.+?)\s*([&|^])\s*(.+?)\s*$', ' foo | bar & lol ').groups()
('foo', '|', 'bar & lol')
```